# How to translate existing PHP project to different language?

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation, zend-translate

I've looked over the web and I couldnt find an appropriate solution.
I think I could use [Zend Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html) over the new project, but how to implent it over the existing one?

There lots of native strings - in html, in PHP and in SQL.  Whats is the best way to find them all and replace with functions? And is it possible to run such functions over the SQL query results?

Answer (score 0):

There really is no *best way*. There only is the way that best fits your needs, and from your question those needs aren't really clear to me. I used `Zend_Translate` in some of my projects and it worked well for the needs I had.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way should be to tweek you DB and your SQL queries to fit your needs depending on some variable set by the user or automatically by you.

You could also just use XML, JSON, txt files and so on.

This is more of a structural problem you need to think about than PHP coding, PHP lets you do whatever you want, you just need to decide how you're going to achieve this depending on your actual project structure.